# It is possible that a weblogic ssl communication accept all certificates?

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, ssl-certificate, keystore

I want to implement a client application to get some information of a weblogic server. The communication has to be secure because the weblogic server is configure secure.

Now I'm able to establish a ssl communication. With following settings:

```
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.TrustKeyStore", "CustomTrust");
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName", tmpTruststore.getAbsolutePath());
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase", "somePW");
System.setProperty("weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType",  "JKS");
```

It is possible that a weblogic ssl communication accept all certificates? It would make the application more convenient in handling. I think of a solution similar to the override of X509TrustManager.
If so, can someone give me an example? Otherwise can you give me an answer with the reasons?

Comment: It is not secured to trust all certificates. You are can not avoid MiM (Man In the Middle) attack

Comment: I know this fact. But is there a possibility to fake a TrustManager or something like this?

Comment: What are you asking? How to hack into a server? If it's your server just change the SSL settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. Having an SSL connection between two entities in which one accepts all data defeats the purpose of having a secure connection. Either use a non-SSL port for convenience or configure the trust stores for security. Can't have both. Sorry.